# Are millennials and generation Z more politically conscious than previous generations?

Tags: united-states, parties, demographics

When I was growing up, my generation (gen X) was rather apathetic in our youth. Politics was the boring stuff done *up there* with little bearing on what's *happening down here*. It was the realm of adults whose job it was to run society. We had better things to do like rock out to the latest music, rebel against our parents, and fit in with our peers. Discussing politics in most social situations was considered nerdy and weird: you were supposed to shut up and drink your beer. Unlike other countries, part of being American then was the luxury of not to caring about your government.

After the election of George W Bush in 2000, I noticed a huge change. All of a sudden, the music stopped and the harsh lights were turned on. The cops shut down the party and everyone was sent home. The booming economy was over.  For the first time, we started discussing politics openly and sorting each other out based on political ideology. If you didn't have one, then you better find one. The old "I don't get into politics" made you a nerd and uncool. We discovered politics had real consequences in our lives. There was the ongoing threat of being drafted, economic uncertainty, and hyper-vigilance after the shock of 9/11.

Ever since then, I've notice younger generations are even more politically minded. The election of Obama, the first black president followed by Trump, a ubiquitous American pop culture icon, increased political interest to the same level as what happened on last night's nationally popular sitcom episode. Washington now has more in common with Hollywood, an endless source of reality-based entertainment.

While I don't have any statistics to support it, it appears Millennials and Generation Z are more politically conscious than previous American generations. Is this a misperception on my part? To be clear, I define consciousness as different from participation. Meaning even if they do or don't participate in the political process, i.e. voting and running for office, politics is as interesting to them as the latest fashion, latest hit song, etc.

Comment: Is this question specific to the USA, or are you interested in worldwide answers?  The answer might be wildly different in Russia or Senegal compared to the USA or Finland.  Also, why is this tagged [tag:parties]?  Political participation is not limited to political parties, in particular not in a country like the USA, where the two-party system does such a poor job to represent the people.

Comment: As a gen-X'er (but an import), I have to say it doesn't look like it, to be completely honest. I attended a couple of the big protests in 2003, and that movement was guided by folks from the vietnam war generation. They were still there for Occupy Wall Street too, as the litmus test of the financial crisis - in which the Obama administration was forced to pick a side, as it were. After that, leftist populism in the US was defeated. The initiative is now with conservative right-populists, who became the default outlet to people disillusioned with their interests being neglected.

Comment: Isn't this a bit ignorant? The previous generations were way more politically active than the current generations, with the civil rights movement, the Vietnam war, the red scare, etc. People back then actually banded together to create strategies to create organized protests, arrests, and we're willing to sacrifice their lives for their ideologies (I recommend reading up on the history of the civil rights movement, it was decades of planning just selecting who will represent the movement). I think Gen X should be focus of the question, instead of current generations.

Comment: Cue the "No, way, my generation was much better than..." remarks.  It is a little difficult to compare across timelines when the same challenges weren't present and when the social media outrage-o-meter was absent in the past.  It's like the "Greatest Generation" thing:  yes, impressive courage, but who's to say a latter generation would not have risen to the circumstances?

Comment: @uberhaxed I specifically mentioned how my generation (Gen X) and later generations as a whole across ideological leanings. The 60s generation was a much larger group, making its outliers stand out more. They certainly weren't in the majority. The Civil Rights Movement was supported by a small fraction of the population and the majority also supported the Vietnam war.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It's precisely my question. Again, I'm talking about politics as an everyday discussion among friends and family. Politics is certainly more entertaining and as interesting as hearing the latest gossip about your favorite rock star or actor. Social media definitely plays a role, but it started much earlier.

Comment: Are they **really** more politically conscious **on average**? Don't forget that social media acts as a great filter, it increases the voices of activist groups and does not give as much platform to more mundane topics, so political activists seem more numerous than how they really are. Social media also rewards outrage, as more people click on it and comment on it, therefore controversial political and ideological topics tend to be much more visible online than in real-life discussions.

Comment: This seems more like a function of the internet than a function of age (although younger people are online more). The internet enables people to be more conscious of what's happening in their country and in the world, which is basically what "politics" is (and social media in particular quite aggressively pushes national and international news into people's faces). That said, the internet and social media is also good at enabling echo chambers and over- or under-representing things, so there may be more political consciousness, but the understanding isn't necessarily more/as accurate.

Comment: The 60s generation was a much larger group of what? I don't understand what you're attempting to clarify here. The population of the present is much larger than the 60s. The civil rights movement isn't just a movement about minorities, it also included things like rights for women, which is a majority in almost every place in the world. And supporting the Vietnam war is being politically active; the only explanation for supporting sending your countrymen to fight a war on the other side of the world is because of the red scare.

Comment: The internet also makes it way easier to email, not snail mail, your representative.  And to google said representative's contact info in the first place.  And, yes, to *pose* as an activist as well.  For all age groups, though older people will struggle with tech.  So, a good question, which I've upvoted, but evolving factors and circumstances makes for a case of apple and oranges.  Along with who is going to be the most vocal defending "their" generational turf here.  Younger voters have always voted less tho and Phillip's answer looks like less like a trend than circumstantial spikes.

Comment: I think they are just more easily manipulated into noisy action.

Answer (score 19):

"Political consciousness" is hard to measure directly. But if we consider election participation a good proxy for interest in politics, then we can indeed see a trend in [this statistic about voter participation in US presidential elections by age group](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1096299/voter-turnout-presidential-elections-by-age-historical/).

[image: us presidential election voter turnout by age group]

What we see here is that the participation of the 18-24 demographic took a notable dip in the late 90s and then spiked in 2020 to almost the level of the very political youth of the 1960s.

To be fair, all other age groups follow a similar trend of falling and raising election participation over the years. But the trend is indeed most apparent in this particular age group.

Interestingly, this cultural discrepancy seems to disappear as people get older. Otherwise we would see the spike of 1992 and the dip of 1996 and 2000 again in the curve for the 25-44 cohort 8 years later.

Comment: Wow! Not only is it most apparent, it's occurring during a time of relative peace when there's no major war or draft. It would be safe to say nothing gets you up off your ass and into a voting booth like the prospect of being sent to a battlefield.

Comment: @ATL_DEV That would be my generation, toward whom I know there is a lot of dislike. (I'm a boomer.) We were a very politically active generation when we were young. I have to wonder myself WTF happened to my generation.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I suspect that in the US, Donald Trump has motivated a lot of younger adults to become more politically aware (and to vote), and probably not in the way Mr. Trump would want them to vote.

Comment: 1996 and 2012 are the second terms for Clinton and Obama, and then 2000 and 2016 were open elections after a period of Democratic rule - and those are the 4 lowest voter turnouts for the 18-24 group in the last 30 years. Looks to me like the young 'ens really don't like Reps being in charge, but get complacent when Dems are running the show.

Comment: @codeMonkey If by "young'ens" you mean under-65s, then maybe. Because only the 65+ group isn't showing that trend.

Comment: In the US, I'd look at participation rates in primary elections. That's where the intra-party shifts that really dictate generational changes in policy, have a potential connection to the public. The general election is reduced to a 1-bit process, and cuts out most states or congressional districts from being venues in policy debate (since most states and districts aren't competitive).

Comment: Worth noting that the drop in the youth vote early on was due to the reduction of the voting age from age 21 to age 18.

Comment: @PeteW There is less data on primary election participation and it isn't consistent nationally since the process is different from state to state, or from election to election, because often one or both primaries aren't seriously contested.

Comment: re: "Political consciousness" is hard to measure directly."  That's almost an understatement when it comes to generational divide.  Older people are, by definition, more experienced by the virtue of having lived through more and having had more time to learn about the world.  So an apples to apples comparison is impossible here.  One can try comparing people of the same ages throughout different times, but that's also influenced by changes in technologies used to access information.  The question is almost guaranteed to be subjective (although it is interesting obviously).

Comment: This graph may illustrate variations in how politically *active* different age groups have been, but says very little about how politically *concious* they have been.

Comment: As stated in the very first sentence of the answer. Since we can't measure consciousness easily, we use activity as a proxy.

Comment: *"all other age groups follow a similar trend"* -> but the 65+ group, which follows a different pattern (with a steady increase in participation)

Answer (score 3):

An addendum to Phillips answer.

The graph is better if you show where people exist.

This isn't accounting for general trends like others mentioned, but looking at compositions, we can see a consistent gain in groups/trends where Mills and Z were active, vs a general drop in groups where Boomers and X are plentiful

[image: BoomersExtracted]
[image: XExtracted]
[image: MillenialsExtracted]
[image: ZExtracted]

[Source for generation age definitions](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/which-age-range-who-generation-z-millennial-boomer-zoomer-b1073540.html&ved=2ahUKEwienYOWrZ2FAxXQnFYBHWzNB2gQFnoECBMQAw&usg=AOvVaw1WFl3fjMZNpm0O9y72biA8)
[Source for data, same as Phillip](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1096299/voter-turnout-presidential-elections-by-age-historical/)

Comment: (Done with Paint, so if someone wants to regraph with proper trendlines, I'd love to replace this pic)

Comment: Just noticed that the X line for 18-25 could possibly be extended to 2004, which would change the direction significantly. This is due to me getting different definitions of age ranges for generations each time I googled it. It was not intentional!

Comment: Nice.  2 graphing suggestions:  put your lines at the bottom, horizontally.  and pick higher contrast (most infographics  gets that wrong).  Here's a [6 col high-contrast palette](https://www.schemecolor.com/high-contrast.php).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Thanks! I'll try to keep that in mind. As for the position of my lines--the original lines are at the bottom, my additions are on the right

Answer (score 2):

> While Voice and Equality focuses heavily on class differences and the
> influence of money in political participation, Verba, Schlozman, and
> Brady (1995) did not take an in depth look into the differences in
> civic participation among various age groups. Dalton (2016) replicated
> the research design from Voice and Equality to identify how civil
> participation has evolved over the last few decades while focusing on
> generational differences. **Using data from the General Social Survey,
> he measured the change from 1967 to 2014 in levels of participation in
> political activities. Dalton (2016) found that in many ways the level
> of political participation has increased. Today, people are more
> likely to contribute money to politicians, write letters to their
> representatives, work on a campaign, and even participate in a boycott
> or march than they were in the 1960s or 1980s.** Voting, however, has
> had a significant drop in participation levels, especially among the
> millennial generation. Dalton (2016) found that the Millennial
> generation has the lowest voter turnout of any generational group of
> young voters and argues that “it is unclear whether the Millennial
> generation can ever catch up to earlier generations” (p. 6).

https://core.ac.uk/download/229112648.pdf

Millennials are more involved in other aspects of politics except voting, so in fact that type of participation could be used as a proxy for measuring political savviness, at least, it could be argued so. However, participation in voting has decreased significantly compared to previous generations, perhaps suggesting that they think that there are more effective ways to participate in the democratic system.

Comment: Note that without more details you could have 20% who vote and do stuff more, with 80% who just vote less.  I have a hard believing in "doesn't vote, but is politically active" as a wide phenomenon.  Neither Phillip's answer, not [census data](https://www.census.gov/library/visualizations/time-series/demo/voting-historical-time-series.html) really supports "millenials => lowest voter turnout ever".  Young people may also be voting more during wars, making peace time cohorts look bad.  Last,  the current(?) trend of "all politicians suck" could be ramping up apathy.